# Fetch file list from Branch using Azure devops git rest api

Tags: java, azure-devops-rest-api

Exact rest api is needed for fetching file list from a branch using Azure Devops Rest Api.

Comment: What have you tried? What research have you done? What isn't working with your implementation?

Comment: I am not getting exact rest api endpoints to fetch all file list from a branch using azure devops rest api. If you could help, it will be helpful for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Fetch file list from Branch using Azure devops git rest api

You could use the REST API [Items - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/Items/List?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#gitversionoptions) with query string parameter `versionDescriptor.version` and `recursionLevel`, documented as Version string identifier (name of tag/**branch**, SHA1 of commit).

So, we could use following URL:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/items?recursionLevel=Full&versionDescriptor.version=<YourBranchName>&api-version=5.0
```

Code sample:

```
$connectionToken="Your PAT"
$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))

$Itemlisturl = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/items?recursionLevel=Full&versionDescriptor.version=master&api-version=5.0"
$ItemlistInfo = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Itemlisturl -Method Get -UseDefaultCredential -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}) 

$ItemlistName= $ItemlistInfo.value.path


Write-Host "The list items of the branch master is = $($ItemlistName | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"
```

The test result:

[image]

Comment: This help us a lot. its turns out you need to use a PAT to get recursion to work. if you are just testing the URLs in the browser recursionLevel seems to default to 'none' even if its set in the request